# What is the MySQL command to check if a field of table A is already referenced to a field of table B as the foreign key?

Tags: mysql

As the question says, what is the MySQL command to check if a field of table A is already referenced to a field of table B as the foreign key? Are there any commands to let the user know it?

Comment: looks like you wanna `JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:-

```
USE information_schema;
SELECT *
FROM
  KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
  REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'A'
  AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = 'A_id';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the systems table for this purpose, however from your previous question I think this might be the wrong way to achieve whatever you are trying to achieve.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-sys-foreign-table.html